# JS: Changing an input's text(value) on file input file select

Tags: javascript, html, forms, events, input

I have successfully created an HTML form that gets a file from a user and also allows giving a name for the file. I have also succeeded in creating a javascript function that can get the name of the file from the upload stream, and only the name (without the path and extension). **Problem is,** I somewhat do not manage to change the input that's there for renaming the upload like I want to. Here is the working function with two demonstrative alerts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateInput(val) {
    som = val.split('\\')[val.split('\\').length - 1];
    som = som.split('.')[0];
    alert('Hey 1');
    fileName.value = som;
    alert('Hey 2');
}; </script>
```

"Hey 1" alert is displayed and it's alright.
"Hey 2" is actually **not** displayed!
fileName is both the **name** and **id** of the input for the *file's name*, I **DID** try using document.getElementById('fileName').value = ... but with no luck.

**Declaration of fileName:**

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="fileName" name="fileName" />
```

The javascript is located in the code under this input. The uploadImage input (which is type of file) is above this input. (Yes, the event is called and som gets the value I want it to have)

**I am trying to change the value of an input:text element. I will try the var thing.*

**THANK YOU IF YOU CAN HELP!**

Comment: Can we see the html portion where the input field is declared?

Comment: Are you trying to set the `value` of an `input:file` element? Or am I misreading? Anyways, why do you expect `fileName.value = som;` to work?

Comment: Probably want to put `var` in front of `som` so it's declared as a local variable.  Also, what is the `fileName` variable?  It isn't declared here so we don't know what it is.

Comment: I am trying to change the value of an input:text element. I will try the var thing.
I expect fileName.value = som; or document.GetElementById('fileName').value = som; to work, because I saw that around the internet and they had no complaints.
Adding the declaration on the main message.

Comment: What is `fileName` variable? How do you get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, code below should work fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateInput(val) {
    var som = val.split('\\')[val.split('\\').length - 1];
    som = som.split('.')[0];
    alert('Hey 1');
    document.getElementById('<%=fileName.ClientID %>').value = som;
    alert('Hey 2');
}; </script>
```

Because of `runat="server"`, id of an element in browser will be different from one you see in your `.aspx` file. Id of HTML element will be something like `CotentPlaceholder1_fileName`, so `document.getElementById('fileName')` will not find it and `document.getElementById('fileName').value = son;` will throw an error.

The same problem with `fileName.value = som;` - as far as I understand, you are trying to use feature of IE (not sure if it is IE only feature, I just never use it but remember that there is something like that) which creates variables in global namespace using IDs of elements. ID is different from fileName, so variable name is different also.

To get an id of an `runat="server"` element like it will be in browser, you can use [`.ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property of server side object.

Also, you should use `var` to define a variable inside a function scope. Like `var som = val.split('\\')[val.split('\\').length - 1];`. This way it will not be visible in global scope (outside of `updateInput` function). Otherwise you may potentially get problems with it in future

Comment: Thank you! It worked :) Hopefully I'll pass it on if I see someone having the same problem.